# NSDateFormatter takes incorrect time interval

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nstimeinterval

I have the method below to format a duration (in seconds) to a string of the format @"mm:ss". Whenever the particular value of 60 is entered, this method behaves unexpected:

- duration = 59 -> @"00:59"
- duration = 60 -> @"59:59" (expected @"01:00")
- duration = 61 -> @"01:01"

The method:

```
+ (NSString *)formatDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{    
    NSDateFormatter *durationFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [durationFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *zeroComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    zeroComponents.hour = 0;
    zeroComponents.minute = 0;
    zeroComponents.second = 0;

    NSDate *zeroDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:zeroComponents];
    [zeroComponents release];
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:duration sinceDate:zeroDate];

    return [[durationFormatter autorelease] stringFromDate:endDate];
}
```

Comment: working great for me as i don't see any error

Comment: Well, after restarting Xcode, it's working here as well :/ It had been doing this for a few days now and a clean did not help... Sorry and thanks for testing it!